# Application Verifier does not allow to start my application

Tags: c++, windbg

I enabled heap options for my application and then started the application. But it failed to start with the following error message. My application is a DCOM server. When I tried to debug the application, it fails to execute even before executing ***main*** method.

What could be the problems? The application started up properly after disabling Application Verifier options and enabling full page heap with Gflags.exe

*The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000005).*

Please help me

Comment: That error means some DLL is failing to be loaded.

Comment: I haven't tried application verifier with COM/DCOM servers, but it's likely that it's unable to work with them. I've tried a lot of other profiling/analysis tools with COM servers and none of them work very well, if at all.

Comment: I cannot start any applications with Heap Option enabled in Application Verifier in a particular machine. Not DCOM server alone. I tested that only now

Answer (score 0):

0xC000005 is an access violation, e.g. Null Pointer dereference. Theoretically, this could be caused by a failed `GetProcAddress` after a failed `LoadLibrary`. Considering the Heap Option changes the behavior, I don't suspect `GetProcAddress` but rather `malloc`, called somewhere in a constructor for a global. (If you'd use `operator new` instead of `malloc`, you'd have an uncaught C++ exception)